Javaに関して。ビルドの正しい方法について教えてください。
javaに関する質問です。プログラミングに関しては完全な初心者です。
以下のgithubで配信されている、ゲーム内のパズルを解くjavaのプログラムを使用したいのですが、バージョンが古く動かすことできません。
そこで、自分でCoreImpoter.javaファイルを現在のゲームのバージョンに合わせた状態に編集して実行可能な状態にしたいです。
https://github.com/BCybercell/IdleChampionsModronAI
リンクからzipファイルをダウンロードして、srcフォルダ内のCoreImpoter.javaを編集後
コマンドプロンプトで
javac -cp gson-2.8.7.jar;json-simple-1.1.1.jar src/*.java

を実行し、srcフォルダに移動してjava Homeを実行したところ
G:IdleChampionsModronAI-main\IdleChampionsModronAI-main\src>java Home
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(Object)" because "this.popSpinner" is null
        at Home.<init>(Home.java:14)
        at Home.main(Home.java:42)

と表示されてしまいました。
配布先の記述に合わせて、javaのバージョンは
java version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)

として、pathは通してあります。
そもそもビルドの仕方が合っているのかもわからないため、プログラムが動く状態までの方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

javac -cp ModronAI.jar:json-simple-1.1.1.jar:gson-2.8.7.jar -d target src/*.java
java -cp ModronAI.jar:json-simple-1.1.1.jar:gson-2.8.7.jar:target Home

でどうでしょうか。
実行時にもクラスパスに一連のjarを含める必要があります。

実行したところ
エラー: メイン・クラスHomeを検出およびロードできませんでした 原因: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Home
となりました。
IntelliJ IDEAを導入したところ実行自体は上手くいきましたので本題は解決とさせてください。 実際にプログラムを動作させたところ
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:322) at GeneticAlgorithm.tournamentSelection(GeneticAlgorithm.java:562) at GeneticAlgorithm.RunLongDNAMultiCore(GeneticAlgorithm.java:217) at Home$exec_class.run(Home.java:108) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
となりますが、こちらはまずは自力で頑張ってみます。

最初に書かれているエラーの原因は、コンパイル結果を出力するディレクトリ(上記コマンドでは target 。このディレクトリに *.class が出力されていると思います)を実行時のクラスパスに含めていないからだと思います。1行目と2行目では -cp オプションの設定値が違うことに注意してください。
